# switch play and pause YouTube video and add progress bar with javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube, progress-bar, pause

After the play button question solved ,I added pause button to the video and it is as show :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class='py-3' ><?php echo $course_name?></div>
        <div style='pointer-events: none' id="video-placeholder" class='w-100'>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" id="player"  src="<?php echo $course_video?>" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        
        <div id='controls' class='row w-100 justify-content-center mt-3'>
            <i id="play" class="material-icons">play_arrow</i>
            <i id="pause" class="material-icons">pause</i>
            <input type="range" id="progress-bar" value="0">
        </div>
    </div>
```

the JavaScript is :

```
$('#play').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#player")[0].src += "?autoplay=1";
        }),
        $('#pause').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#player")[0].src += "?autoplay=0";
        })
```

when I click play icon it is play the video ,then when I click the pause icon it is pause the video ,but when I return to click on play icon it doesn't play ,How can make it play and pause all time I clicked? and How can active the progress bar?

Comment: Dont change the source. Stop/pause and play the video

Comment: How can i do that Sir?

Comment: See the dupe...

Comment: i hope unclose this question because i solved it with this codes without using YouTube API

Comment: @SM_Berwari You should post your answer in the linked duplicate thread if it fits. We try to collect similar solutions in one place.

Comment: @SM_Berwari Please don't add your solution to the question, that is against the rules. See my previous comment for an alternative.

Comment: the solution of the other post is not clear and it doesn't work with me?